# How to read a text file into a multi dimensional array in pseudocode?

Tags: multidimensional-array, text-files, pseudocode

I have the multidimensional array: 
`Sales (Town, Month, Product)`

I have a text file containing the following:

> "ABC" Jun 50 "DEF" Apr 100 "HIJ" Jun 90 "KLM" Jun 55 "NOP" Jun 65

Where the first word is Town, the second word is month & the third word is product. It then repeats for the 4-6 words, 7-9 words, etc.

How would I read my text file into the multidimensional array in pseudocode?

Comment: ideally if you can have a way of having the records in this order

"ABC" Jun 50,"DEF" Apr 100,"HIJ" Jun 90,"KLM" Jun 55,"NOP" Jun 65
then you can split the string by , to get a string array of sales entries and then split that by a space to get individual elemtns , town month and product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create an **list** of sales.
2. read  one word and save it as **town**
3. read  one word and save it as **month**
4. read  one word and save it as **product**
5. create **sales object** from **town**, **month** and **product** read on step 2, 3 and 4.
6. add this **sales object** to the sales **list**
7. go to step 2 if *end of file* is not reached yet.

Comment: What do you mean by an object? What would the equivalent be in Pascal or Python?

Comment: In python you can use tuple.a three element tuple. A three element array would work for all other language.

Comment: So the result would look something like:
sales_list = [("ABC", Jun, 50),("DEF", Apr, 100),("HIJ", Jun, 90)]

Comment: Yes, But if you like you can make it `sales_list = [["ABC", Jun, 50],["DEF", Apr, 100],["HIJ", Jun, 90]]`. Means array of arrays. it completely depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array/list/other collection of structures/classes, instead of multi-dimantional arrays (emphasis on *structure* and *class*).

With the proper strucutre, you can read the input as a series of structures, instead of multi-dimentional data.  This will help with optional fields as well and makes your code and data-handling more organized